# How to generate a sine wave in python?

Tags: python-3.x, data-processing, sine-wave, python-dataset

To generate a csv file where each column is a data of sine wave of frequency 1 Hz, 2 Hz, 3Hz, 4Hz, 5Hz, 6Hz and 7 Hz. The amplitude is one volt. There should be 100 points in one cycle and thus 700 points in seven waves.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how I will go about it:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

freqs = list(range(1, 9))
time = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 100)
data = {f"{freq}Hz": np.sin(2 * np.pi * freq * time) for freq in freqs}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.head()
```

[image]

Comment: can we add sampling points to the code. If so, does the pandas DataFrame hold columns with different lengths? Kindly clarify my doubts@quest

Comment: All DataFrames columns must have the same length. You can append NAs to the ones with fewer values. you can modify `time = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 100)` to the times you need values at. you can also have different times for different frequencies.